# RSpec view specs - Check that layout yields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I want to check that my layout yields (either with no args or for specific content):

```
<%= yield %>
<%= yield :something %>
```

I've got something like this in my view spec:

```
let(:page) { Capybara::Node::Simple.new(rendered) }

before do
  # I want to stub the 'yield' stuff here

  render
end

it { should have_css 'my yielded stuff' }
```

but I can't find a way to to stub the yield execution.

I prefer to avoid using a sample view with the given layout to simulate the rendering.

Comment: Why not you do _feature_ test ? That's simple, elegant and worthy.

Comment: You can set the content for a "named" yield by `view.instance_variable_get("@view_flow").set(:something, "Hello World")` but I don't like digging into the internals of how the rails rendering works. And most of your feature tests should catch if your layout is missing the main yield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this view spec to test that my layout yields:

```
describe 'layouts/application.html.slim' do
  it 'yields a subview' do
    render text: 'a subview', layout: 'layouts/application'
    expect(rendered).to have_text('a subview')
  end
end
```